# build model for parsing Json containing nested array using GSON

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

i used [json to pojo tools](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) in order to parse the following json :

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "orders": 5
    },
    {
      "orders": 20
    },
    [
      {
        "day": 16,
        "orders": 1
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

json to pojo tools has generated the following two models

```
public class Result {

  @SerializedName("orders")
  @Expose
  private Long orders;

  public Long getOrders() {
      return orders;
  }

  public void setOrders(Long orders) {
      this.orders = orders;
  }
}

public class Example {

  @SerializedName("result")
  @Expose
  private List<Result> result = null;

  public List<Result> getResult() {
      return result;
  }

  public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
      this.result = result;
  }
}
```

However, it fails to parse the last json format, specially the nested array as it didn't include it in generated models. any body can assist ?
Your response is appreciated.

Comment: I think problem is your json object. Delete [
      {
        "day": 16,
        "orders": 1
      }
    ] then it works fine

Comment: You need to Code your own custom TypeAdaptor for GSON you have created.

Following link may help you: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gson/gson_custom_adapters.htm

Answer (score 1):

try this after edit your Example class

```
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private List<Result> result = null;

    public List<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public class Result {

        @SerializedName("orders")
        @Expose
        private Integer orders;

        public Integer getOrders() {
            return orders;
        }

        public void setOrders(Integer orders) {
            this.orders = orders;
        }

    }
}
```

I hope it will work with you .